# Display XML object that also contains a list in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, xml

I am receiving xml data from an API. The xml object goes something like this:

```
<OrderHeader xmlns="xml.org">
<ResponseCode>1000</ResponseCode>
<Message>Order Received</Message>
<OrderId>10230192</OrderId>
<lstOrderTracking>
    <OrderTracking>
         <TrackingStatus>Order Received </TrackingStatus>
         <Address> ABC </Address>
         <Other> And some other stuff </Other>
    </OrderTracking>
    <OrderTracking>
         <TrackingStatus>Order Complete </TrackingStatus>
         <Address> ABC </Address>
         <Other> And some other stuff </Other>
    </OrderTracking>
</lstOrderTracking>
</OrderHeader>
```

I am able to display Header fields successfully but no luck in displaying the list items.

This is my code:

```
$scope.result = response;

if (window.DOMParser)
{
     parser=new DOMParser();
     xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(response,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
     xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
     xmlDoc.async=false;
     xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
}
$scope.ResponseCode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ResponseCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
$scope.Message = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
$scope.OrderId = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("OrderId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

$scope.data = response;
```

And in HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ResponseCode
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ResponseCode}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Message
            </td>
            <td>
                {{Message}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                OrderID
            </td>
            <td>
                {{OrderId}}
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

<div ng-repeat="x in data.lstOrderTracking.OrderTracking">
      {{x.TrackingStatus}}
</div>
```

How to do I display list items? And is there a better way to parse XML in Angular?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pj5br/ as a reference

Comment: that's for json. I need xml solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally convert your XML to JSON. See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pHItZhnExN7CZA3JVAGr?p=preview).

```
// Code goes here
angular.module("test", [])

.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    var xml = '<OrderHeader><ResponseCode>1000</ResponseCode><Message>Order Received</Message><OrderId>10230192</OrderId><lstOrderTracking><OrderTracking><TrackingStatus>Order Received </TrackingStatus><Address> ABC </Address><Other> And some other stuff </Other></OrderTracking><OrderTracking><TrackingStatus>Order Complete </TrackingStatus><Address> ABC </Address><Other> And some other stuff </Other></OrderTracking></lstOrderTracking></OrderHeader>';
    $scope.json = xmlToJSON.parseString(xml);
});
```

And the function I [found](https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON):

```
/* Copyright 2015 William Summers, MetaTribal LLC
 * adapted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JXON
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
/**
 * @author William Summers
 *
 */

var xmlToJSON = (function () {

    this.version = "1.3";

    var options = { // set up the default options
        mergeCDATA: true, // extract cdata and merge with text
        grokAttr: true, // convert truthy attributes to boolean, etc
        grokText: true, // convert truthy text/attr to boolean, etc
        normalize: true, // collapse multiple spaces to single space
        xmlns: true, // include namespaces as attribute in output
        namespaceKey: '_ns', // tag name for namespace objects
        textKey: '_text', // tag name for text nodes
        valueKey: '_value', // tag name for attribute values
        attrKey: '_attr', // tag for attr groups
        cdataKey: '_cdata', // tag for cdata nodes (ignored if mergeCDATA is true)
        attrsAsObject: true, // if false, key is used as prefix to name, set prefix to '' to merge children and attrs.
        stripAttrPrefix: true, // remove namespace prefixes from attributes
        stripElemPrefix: true, // for elements of same name in diff namespaces, you can enable namespaces and access the nskey property
        childrenAsArray: true // force children into arrays
    };

    var prefixMatch = new RegExp(/(?!xmlns)^.*:/);
    var trimMatch = new RegExp(/^\s+|\s+$/g);

    this.grokType = function (sValue) {
        if (/^\s*$/.test(sValue)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (/^(?:true|false)$/i.test(sValue)) {
            return sValue.toLowerCase() === "true";
        }
        if (isFinite(sValue)) {
            return parseFloat(sValue);
        }
        return sValue;
    };

    this.parseString = function (xmlString, opt) {
        return this.parseXML(this.stringToXML(xmlString), opt);
    }

    this.parseXML = function (oXMLParent, opt) {

        // initialize options
        for (var key in opt) {
            options[key] = opt[key];
        }

        var vResult = {},
            nLength = 0,
            sCollectedTxt = "";

        // parse namespace information
        if (options.xmlns && oXMLParent.namespaceURI) {
            vResult[options.namespaceKey] = oXMLParent.namespaceURI;
        }

        // parse attributes
        // using attributes property instead of hasAttributes method to support older browsers
        if (oXMLParent.attributes && oXMLParent.attributes.length > 0) {
            var vAttribs = {};

            for (nLength; nLength < oXMLParent.attributes.length; nLength++) {
                var oAttrib = oXMLParent.attributes.item(nLength);
                vContent = {};
                var attribName = '';

                if (options.stripAttrPrefix) {
                    attribName = oAttrib.name.replace(prefixMatch, '');

                } else {
                    attribName = oAttrib.name;
                }

                if (options.grokAttr) {
                    vContent[options.valueKey] = this.grokType(oAttrib.value.replace(trimMatch, ''));
                } else {
                    vContent[options.valueKey] = oAttrib.value.replace(trimMatch, '');
                }

                if (options.xmlns && oAttrib.namespaceURI) {
                    vContent[options.namespaceKey] = oAttrib.namespaceURI;
                }

                if (options.attrsAsObject) { // attributes with same local name must enable prefixes
                    vAttribs[attribName] = vContent;
                } else {
                    vResult[options.attrKey + attribName] = vContent;
                }
            }

            if (options.attrsAsObject) {
                vResult[options.attrKey] = vAttribs;
            } else {}
        }

        // iterate over the children
        if (oXMLParent.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (var oNode, sProp, vContent, nItem = 0; nItem < oXMLParent.childNodes.length; nItem++) {
                oNode = oXMLParent.childNodes.item(nItem);

                if (oNode.nodeType === 4) {
                    if (options.mergeCDATA) {
                        sCollectedTxt += oNode.nodeValue;
                    } else {
                        if (vResult.hasOwnProperty(options.cdataKey)) {
                            if (vResult[options.cdataKey].constructor !== Array) {
                                vResult[options.cdataKey] = [vResult[options.cdataKey]];
                            }
                            vResult[options.cdataKey].push(oNode.nodeValue);

                        } else {
                            if (options.childrenAsArray) {
                                vResult[options.cdataKey] = [];
                                vResult[options.cdataKey].push(oNode.nodeValue);
                            } else {
                                vResult[options.cdataKey] = oNode.nodeValue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } /* nodeType is "CDATASection" (4) */
                else if (oNode.nodeType === 3) {
                    sCollectedTxt += oNode.nodeValue;
                } /* nodeType is "Text" (3) */
                else if (oNode.nodeType === 1) { /* nodeType is "Element" (1) */

                    if (nLength === 0) {
                        vResult = {};
                    }

                    // using nodeName to support browser (IE) implementation with no 'localName' property
                    if (options.stripElemPrefix) {
                        sProp = oNode.nodeName.replace(prefixMatch, '');
                    } else {
                        sProp = oNode.nodeName;
                    }

                    vContent = xmlToJSON.parseXML(oNode);

                    if (vResult.hasOwnProperty(sProp)) {
                        if (vResult[sProp].constructor !== Array) {
                            vResult[sProp] = [vResult[sProp]];
                        }
                        vResult[sProp].push(vContent);

                    } else {
                        if (options.childrenAsArray) {
                            vResult[sProp] = [];
                            vResult[sProp].push(vContent);
                        } else {
                            vResult[sProp] = vContent;
                        }
                        nLength++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (!sCollectedTxt) { // no children and no text, return null
            if (options.childrenAsArray) {
                vResult[options.textKey] = [];
                vResult[options.textKey].push(null);
            } else {
                vResult[options.textKey] = null;
            }
        }

        if (sCollectedTxt) {
            if (options.grokText) {
                var value = this.grokType(sCollectedTxt.replace(trimMatch, ''));
                if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
                    vResult[options.textKey] = value;
                }
            } else if (options.normalize) {
                vResult[options.textKey] = sCollectedTxt.replace(trimMatch, '').replace(/\s+/g, " ");
            } else {
                vResult[options.textKey] = sCollectedTxt.replace(trimMatch, '');
            }
        }

        return vResult;
    }


    // Convert xmlDocument to a string
    // Returns null on failure
    this.xmlToString = function (xmlDoc) {
        try {
            var xmlString = xmlDoc.xml ? xmlDoc.xml : (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
            return xmlString;
        } catch (err) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Convert a string to XML Node Structure
    // Returns null on failure
    this.stringToXML = function (xmlString) {
        try {
            var xmlDoc = null;

            if (window.DOMParser) {

                var parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

                return xmlDoc;
            } else {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString);

                return xmlDoc;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return this;
}).call({});

if (typeof module != "undefined" && module !== null && module.exports) module.exports = xmlToJSON;
else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) define(function() {return xmlToJSON});
```

Comment: what's wrong with using xml? I need a solution with xml

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. You can directly use the JSON you get as JavaScript objects. Where XML has to be parsed. By using the library I suggested, you won't have to create parse functions for every piece of XML you get.